# C# coding, I need to create several text files and populate it with unsorted lists of integers, then read it from the respective file into a list

Tags: sorting, switch-statement, text-files

```
ArrayList List;
    String FileName;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> Integers = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("Please pick desired list size");
        Console.WriteLine("Use the respective number (1)Small, (2)Medium, (3)Large, or (4)XLarge");
        int size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Randomgen(List);
        
    }
    static void Randomgen(int Size, ArrayList List)
    {
        StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(FileName); ;
        switch (Size)
        {

            case 1:
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
                {
                    List.Add(new Integers(random.Next(1, int.MaxValue)));
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                Random randomM = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 2001; i++)
                {
                    List.Add(new Integers(randomM.Next(1, int.MaxValue)));
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                Random randomL = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 20001; i++)
                {
                    List.Add(new Integers(randomL.Next(1, int.MaxValue)));
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                Random randomXL = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 200001; i++)
                {
                    List.Add(new Integers(randomXL.Next(1, int.MaxValue)));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    static void populateListFromFile(string FileName, ArrayList List)
    {
        StreamReader Input = new StreamReader(FileName);
        while (!Input.EndOfStream)
        {
            List.Add(new Integers(int.Parse(Input.ReadLine())));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("File has been successfully imported");
    }

}
```

****Im trying to create 1 of 4 different text files based of the user selection using the switch case, with an arraylist of unsorted integers and then I want to Streamread back into an arraylist usign my populate listfrom file method, so that I may proceed to sort them later using 3 other sorting methods. the whole point is to measure the efficiency of the algorithms over different amounts of data or list sizes. the main method is giving me trouble though. Most of my knowledge is self studied so please bare with me.

---

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is the problem you are facing, from what I can see, your `Randomgen` function accepts 2 parameters which is `int Size` and `ArrayList List`. However in your call to it in `Main` you are only providing it with 1 parameters `Randomgen(List);`, therefore the whole switch case inside of that function won't work.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to call the method, i tried using the same varaiables taht i used in the randomgen method, but it kept coming up wrong. also new(Integers) by the random next is coming up as a syntax error.Im not sure if im declaring it correctly, but i thought i did in the first line of main